# How to globally set guides in Fontlab

Tags: fonts, vector, guides, glyphs, smart-guides

I want to have this sort of thing:

[image]

There's 6 horizontal lines and 3 vertical lines, to form the sort of bounding box and positioning guides for the character contours. I am new to FontLab and have been unable to successfully "select" the guides, though I can change some of them on an existing font (one glyph at a time).

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to say, select all these glyphs (like 100 glyphs, or all glyphs in the font), and change their guides so they are all the same (this is for monospace font). How can I do this?

I basically want all the glyphs to have the same grid. Ideally, then, too, it would be able to recenter and such automatically, but maybe that's asking for too much.

An example font glyph looks like this in the font.

[image]

1. I don't know how these were originally defined.
2. I can only change that horizontal one at the bottom by double clicking it.
3. I don't see anywhere in the menus for specifying the layout of the grid bars.
4. I don't know how to add new ones, or [where](https://help.fontlab.com/fontlab-vi/Using-Guidelines/) to read in the FontLab docs.
5. I see the locks on some of the grids, but I don't know how to "unlock" them or batch change them all together at once.

So far I got it like this by dragging *some sort of* grid bar onto the page (but those grayed out ones just won't budge):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is](https://help.fontlab.com/fontlab-vi/Guides-tool/)

> To create a global/font guideline, select the Guides tool, hold down Shift and drag the mouse pointer from either the vertical and horizontal Rulers. By default, a font guideline will be depicted by a dotted purple line attached to the ruler perpendicular to it.

[image]